# Does Okular has a way to export or display only the highlighted text?

Tags: okular

Currently, I am aware of the feature in Okular which lets you jump to the parts of the highlighted text from review pane. However, I find it distracting and so I am trying to figure out if there is any way where I can just print the summary of the highlighted text or just view the highlighted text in a continuous format.